# How to understand the upper end of the primary key?

Tags: mysql

In the book <[High Performance MySQL](ftp://203.157.240.9/pub/docs/High.Performance.MySQL.3rd.Edition.pdf)> page 177, there is have a tip about "When Primary Key Order Is Worse"

> For high-concurrency workloads, inserting in primary key order can actually create points of contention in InnoDB. The upper end of the primary key is one hot spot. Because all inserts take place there, concurrent inserts might fight over next-key locks. Another hot spot is the AUTO_INCREMENT locking mechanism; if you experience problems with that, you might be able to redesign your table or application, or configure innodb_autoinc_lock_mode. If your server version doesn’t support innodb_auto inc_lock_mode, you can upgrade to a newer version of InnoDB that will perform better for this specific workload.

How to understand concept **The upper end of the primary key**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book means "the current maximum value of the primary key that's used in the table".

It's saying that if you keep inserting in ascending primary key order then you may impact performance, because (in the case of an auto-increment) "the next value for this primary key" is something that must be generated and used atomically, and because (in other cases) there are implementation factors that make it a bit slower.

If I have a table with rows whose primary key values are `1, 2, 3, 4`, then inserting at the "upper-end" means inserting anything with a primary key value greater than `4`. Obviously in this example you don't have much choice about that!